# how to set TTTabBar column number

Tags: three20

I implemented TTTabBar like this:

```
_tabBar = [[TTTabGrid alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, TTApplicationFrame().size.width-80, TT_ROW_HEIGHT) ];
_tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_tabBar.tabItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"aaa"] autorelease],
                    [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"bbb"] autorelease],
                    nil];
//_tabBar.selectedTabIndex = 1; 

[_tabBar sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.titleView = _tabBar;
```

_tabBar is TTTabBar
but appears three column buttons:
[image]

How to set the column number, coz I just need two buttons here.
And, as you see in my code, I've set initWithTitle:@"aaa" but there is no any title on button. Anything wrong?
WHAT IF I JUST NEED LIKE THIS:
[image]

Two grid buttons

Comment: Figured out that the third "button" is background color, not a real button, but I still not understand: I set two button, why not the second button appears like "Right corner button" and in my code, already [_tabBar sizeToFit] why still leave an empty, not those two buttons filled up title area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set _tabBar.columnCount to 2?

But you are looking for UISegmentedControl with style set to BarStyle.